# Is the phrase "There are many hungers it is better to deny than to feed" correct?

Tags: grammatical-number, dummy-it

The "it is" seems out of place to me. I'd rather have it written as "There are many hungers that/which are better to deny than to feed".

Comment: great question!

Comment: I would use passive voice.  "There are many hungers which are better denied than fed." or "There are hungers which would be better denied than fed."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is not incorrect, it is just awkward.

Whenever I see *there* and *it* used in a sentence, I know I can come up with something better.  Many words in English can both enhance and refine a sentence.

For example, by using *instead of* and *satisfy* in the sentence, we can rearrange it to read:

> It is better to deny many hungers instead of satisfying them.

This version of the sentence is less awkward.  Alternatively:

> Many hungers are best denied rather than satisfied.

This version of the sentence is more concise and stays true to the original meaning.

*There* and *it* are frequently used in spoken English, but written English requires more specific words.

Comment: I don't think it is awkward at all, just going for a different effect than language you use chatting over coffee.

Comment: Quite, Oldcat. It's not at all awkward; just rather poetic.

Sorry Snapman, and more mundane clearly isn't always better